# Get total sum by category using shell command

Tags: shell

I have this sample data. I need to find the total for each color.

Input:

```
Blue,20
Blue,10
Black,13
Red,8
Black,10
Red,10
Blue,21
```

Output:

```
Blue,51
Black,23
Red,18
```

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: trying something like this "awk '{print $NF}' | awk '{n += $1}; END{print  pat n}'" but not getting by each category.

Answer (score 1):

In pure bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A totals=( )
while IFS=, read -r category value; do
  (( totals[$category] += value ))
done

for category in "${!totals[@]}"; do
  sum=${totals[$category]}
  echo "$category,$sum"
done
```

You can see this running -- emitting your desired output for the input at hand -- at https://ideone.com/5Ispzj